# keycloak configuration http-Link in "verify email"

Tags: email, url, hyperlink, keycloak, email-verification

When my users receive the "Please verifiy email link" the Link in the template is always: http://localhost:8280/auth....

First I tried to set the frontend URL in my realm:
[image]

But after this change I cannot start my quarkus-application anymore because I get the following error message: issuer validation error: received [https://myLinkToMyWebsite.com/auth/realms/turniersoftware]

So I removed this setting in keycloak.

I thought that keycloak is using this url for email broadcasts. "Quarkus-portal" is my java-application.
[image]

If I click impersonate user in keycloak and set the action "verifiy email" in keycloak admin web, I get the email verifiy email with the correct link.

If my java-program says "sendVerifyEmail" it will send out with "localhost:8280"

Can someone please explain me, what I have to configure to get the domain in my email broadcasts correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per to the keycloak docs **The default hostname provider uses the configured frontendUrl as the base URL for frontend requests (requests from user-agents) and uses the request URL as the basis for backend requests (direct requests from clients).**
In your case I think the client configured is a `Java client(which is backend)` , so in order to force all the backend requests to pass through the public domain(`frontendUrl`) you might want to set the `forceBackendUrlToFrontendUrl` property to `true` in the `standalone.xml` file.
Please check the below link for further reference.
[Hostname SPI](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_installation/topics/host.adoc)